# MySQL UNION returning no results whatsoever

Tags: php, mysql, select, union

I've been tearing my hair out at my inability to understand what seems to be a very simple issue. I'm making a small Business Contacts System that would enable our company to store the contact details of other business/companies as well as business contacts (can be freelancers or linked to previously added companies. What I'm trying to do is have one search form that would enable me to search for either the name of a contact or the name of a business in both Arabic and English. **What am I doing wrong?**

**UPDATE: The UNION Query works if I remove the Arabic search portions from each query section (i.e. I removed "OR contact_name_arabic LIKE '%".$queryString."%'" as well as "OR company_name_arabic LIKE '%".$queryString."%'")**

This is becoming more complicated :/

**Table 1: Companies**

```
id   |   company_name   |   company_name_arabic
-----------------------------------------------
1    |   Red Arrow      |   السهم الأحمر
2    |   White Tower    |   البرج الأبيض
3    |   Mobilex        |   موبيليكس
```

**Table 2: Contacts**

```
id   |   company_id   |   contact_name   |   contact_name_arabic
----------------------------------------------------------------
1    |       1        |   Saeed Adam     |   سعيد آدم
2    |       1        |   Andrew White   |   أندرو وايت
3    |       2        |   Steve Rogers   |   ستيف روجرز
```

Here is the MySQL statement:

```
$querystring =  "(SELECT contact_name, contact_name_arabic
                            FROM CONTACTS
                            WHERE contact_name LIKE '%".$queryString."%' 
                            OR contact_name_arabic LIKE '%".$queryString."%')
                            UNION
                            (SELECT company_name, company_name_arabic
                            FROM COMPANIES
                            WHERE company_name LIKE '%".$queryString."%' 
                            OR company_name_arabic LIKE '%".$queryString."%')";
```

Thanks!

Comment: try using `UNION ALL`

Comment: Can you elaborate what is not working for you.

Comment: DevZer0 - Doesn't help :/

Mani - I'm trying to pull up any records that match the name of the contact or the name of the company using only one Query String.

The problem is that if I only try to select from one table (i.e. remove the UNION and the second query) it works fine!

Answer (score 0):

```
$querystring =  "SELECT contact_name, contact_name_arabic
                        FROM CONTACTS
                        WHERE (contact_name LIKE '%".$queryString."%' 
                        OR contact_name_arabic LIKE '%".$queryString."%')
                        UNION
                        SELECT company_name, company_name_arabic
                        FROM COMPANIES
                        WHERE (company_name LIKE '%".$queryString."%' 
                        OR company_name_arabic LIKE '%".$queryString."%')";
```

Remove the parenthesis,Mysql will try to run (SELECT blah which is not valid.

EDIT:I added some parentheses, try it.

Comment: Mihai - I removed the parenthesis but still doesn't work. The problem is that if I only try to select from one table (i.e. remove the UNION and the second query) it works fine!

Comment: I`m not sure but if might fail because in the second select it does not find any results.Try to put data in your table so both selects find something so you can test it.Or test the query directly in mysql with existent data.

Comment: Hey Mihai - The Union query works perfectly when I remove the Arabic portion of each Select statement. I'm even more confused now :/

Answer (score 0):

try this query in your mysql query builder

```
(SELECT contact_name, contact_name_arabic
                            FROM CONTACTS
                            WHERE contact_name LIKE '%e%' 
                            OR contact_name_arabic LIKE '%e%')
                            UNION
                            (SELECT company_name, company_name_arabic
                            FROM COMPANIES
                            WHERE company_name LIKE '%e%' 
                            OR company_name_arabic LIKE '%e%')
```

if its working check the value comes in variable $queryString.

and also not need to check  the field  company_name_arabic

```
(SELECT contact_name, contact_name_arabic
                                FROM CONTACTS
                                WHERE contact_name LIKE '%e%')
                                UNION
                                (SELECT company_name, company_name_arabic
                                FROM COMPANIES
                                WHERE company_name LIKE '%e%' )
```